# terminal not taking any commands

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, terminal

I am using react after running cd my-app and npm start it sets up a local host then I can't add anything to the terminal so I can not install anything else or make any changes in the terminal I can't delete or write anything in the terminal area

Answer (score 0):

React's npm start will start server and you can see your application at localhost:3000 in browser, if you need to add any package in app, you can open new terminal in system and go to your project location OR you can open another terminal by clicking "+" in VScode. You can now add another package in application

Also You can add package in same terminal by stopping your application first by(ctrl-z)- add a package and then start app again with npm start.

Comment: thanks it worked I wasn't adding npm start after entering the new package